How can I search for news within my hub using PnP Modern Search box?
I am using SharePoint Online and pnp search box webpart. I would like to use the OOTB search result page. Which querystring can I add to the url to show only news from the associated sites to my hub site?
I try this but it is not working:
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/search.aspx/sitenews?q=testPageTitle&DepartmentId=dc0cbdbb-28b8-4d30-b46d-8bd0b24559bd
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/search.aspx/sitenews?q=testPageTitle&scope=hub

I guess you just want the published news? In that case you should look into PromotedState=2

Try this one: /_layouts/15/search.aspx/news?q=YOURQUERY
